# What will be faster when moving to sd-ext via A2SD+ Data or Dalvik-cache? (or can I move both with no extra-penalty)

Tags: htc-desire, app2sd, miui, dalvik

I'm using `A2SD+` on my `HTC Desire` running on `MIUI`.
Currently only the `app` and `app-private` are under `/sd-ext`, but I'm running out of space very quickly :)

Currently my `dalvik-cache` consumes **46.3MB** and the `data` takes **53.7MB** of internal phone memory, so I think `data` will give me more value, but I'm not 100% sure of that either.

I know I can technically move both `data` and `dalvik-cache` to `/sd-ext`, but I understood there could be performance problems, but I need the space. So my question is which will have a lesser effect on performance? Moving the `data` or the `dalvik-cache`?

EDIT: Some tech info (if it helps):
My SD Card - Kingmax, Class 10, 16GB

I tested with [SD Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ales.veluscek.sdtools&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImFsZXMudmVsdXNjZWsuc2R0b29scyJd) and got these results:
Writing Speed: **8.7 MB/s**
Reading Speed: **18.6 MB/s**

Note that the test was on the FAT32 partition, I don't know if the EXT3 partition I use for the `/sd-ext` will be any faster. The `/sd-ext` partition is **1GB**.

Comment: "Better" based on what criteria?  Are you trying to speed up the phone or save space?  It also depends on the particular apps you use and your usage patterns.

Comment: I rephrased the question better - please see if this is a sufficiently clear question and reopen it.

Comment: I'm still not sure it's really answerable, but we'll give it a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Matthew already stated, there's no unique answer possible to your question -- all depends on your usage patterns. Generally spoken, I'd say moving app data should be preferred: If you move the Dalvik Cache, it would affect **all** your apps -- while moving the app data only affects apps which store some data (and by "some" I mean "data size exceeds their Dalvik-Cache size"), so a good guess is it affects only a few apps. But this can very well be those apps you are using most, and which heavily access their data -- so it may or may not be the better choice in some cases.

Guess you've got to try. I'd suggest starting with the app data. A class 10 card should provide sufficient speed -- so if the results are acceptable to you, stay with this. Otherwise, go back and try with the Dalvik Cache. If this isn't acceptable either, the only choice left is buying a new device with bigger internal storage...

Comment: Summary of my attempts:  
APP - Good,   
Dalvik - Bad