# 35 mb in proc folder

Tags: internal-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My internal storage capacity is running low,  what can I do?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/my-internal-storage-capacity-is-running-low-what-can-i-do)

The phone memory on my HTC Desire is full, I already moved everything I could to the sd-card. In ES File Explorer I found a folder named /proc and it contains 35 MB of maps with numbers, does the phone need these or can I delete these folders or can I move them to the sd-card?

Comment: First of all, don't fall for the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you're really asking is: **How to deal with low storage for apps**. Possible ansers are here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/my-internal-storage-capacity-is-running-low-what-can-i-do or http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/htc-desire-low-on-internal-storage-im-clueless-any-help

Comment: thanks for introducing me to the 'xy problem' as you have propably guessed, it is my first time here and I'm already glad I learned about the xy. Back to the /proc: I searched a while for some information and what comes back in all answers is that it doesn't occupy any space, in my phone it occupies 35 mb and that makes me wonder whether it should be there as it is.

Comment: No problem :-) On my Nexus 7 it's shown as 0bytes however I'm using Linux' standard 'du -sh /proc' in the terminal (my Nexus 7 is modified to include both). I guess it's a bug with ES file explorer to show 35MB. /proc is just a virtual folder that doesn't contain actual files, instead all content is computed on the fly to show you things like /proc/cpuinfo (CPU model information) or /proc/partitions (the **current** setup of disk partitions) or /proc/uptime (the **current** uptime). It's just a means to be able to acces this data in a standard way (file IO) easily.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your direct question:
Deleting stuff in /proc won't help at all, /proc is a virtual folder that doesn't occupy memory on disk. It holds information on running processes, various system data and stats and more.

Please don't randomly delete stuff (also not elsewhere) in hope to free up space for apps. Unless you know what you're doing. Android's file system is somewhat different to what people know from Windows.

Read more on Linux' (which Android is based upon) [File system hierachy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/index.html) and its entry on [/proc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html).

Comment: Thanks for your worries, I won't just delete the thing, was wondering whether it could be deleted, but no, and the /proc-link learned me more on its content, but it keeps me with the question why it is so big.... where it's content should be minimal.

Comment: It doesn't occupy any disk space and it should be reported as 0bytes. On both my Nexus 7 and another handset I got 0bytes (using standard linux tools). Probably *ES file explorer* is buggy and doesn't handle the virtual /proc file system correct.