# Google Play Services taking more and more storage

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, internal-storage, google-play-services

I'm using HTC Desire A8181 with Android version 2.2.2. I'm currently running out of free internal space. Besides of some applications growing bigger from release to release, the greatest space consumer is **Google Play Services**. It is currently using 13,55MB and is automatically upgraded, taking more and more space. Soon I'll be forced to deinstall some of the apps because of that :(

Is there anything I can do with that Google Play Services? For example, can I safely uninstall it, install older version or tell it to move to external storage? My phone has barely 2 years and it's in danger of running unusable, while normally I'm using electronic devices 5 to 10 years...

Comment: Related: [My internal storage capacity is running low, what can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/my-internal-storage-capacity-is-running-low-what-can-i-do)

Answer (score 8):

What [Akas refers to](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/45785/16575) is using the [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) app, which is "kind of" App2SD, but much more flexible: You can get the entire app moved out (not just parts), and can even move apps you otherwise couldn't. But Akas missed one important part: your device **must be rooted** in order to use this special way.

As to the other part of your question: Sure you could uninstall the updates of *Google Play Services* -- but that wouldn't help you in any way, as the app will automatically update itself again. Furthermore, there might be dependencies, as other apps use this service (e.g. *Google Play* to access the playstore, and others). So newer versions of those apps might rely on newer versions of the *Play Services*.

Maybe someone digged (or will dig) a little deeper into all those dependencies and what can be done about them. It might end up in using some "legacy apps" -- like e.g. the [Legacy Playstore](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1809215) ([original post](http://www.modaco.com/topic/356009-r2-legacy-play-store-with-all-purchased-apps-visible/)), while the original ones could be frozen/removed. Maybe all this is possible -- it again would require you to root your device, as these apps need to be installed as system apps.

While we all wish our devices might have a long life: if you look at the specs of your two-years-old, and compare it even with todays low-end devices, you will see the difference. And if you compare app sizes from two years ago ("What? 1 MB app size? Too big!") with todays ("Unfortunately, the play store has a limit of 50 MB app size, were we cannot fit our app into"; with my own words the summary of *LibreOffice for Android*), you see were it goes. And while I fully agree that core services/apps should be kept slim, there's nothing we can do about that...

Enough theory: if your device is rooted, or rooting it is acceptable (and doable) for you: Akas recommendation seems the best way out for you.

Answer (score 2):

If your phone is rooted, you can partition your SD card and move Google Play Services app on to your SD card. That could free up a lot of space. You can use this method to safely transfer all your apps(except the system apps) to your SD card. The procedure for partitioning and transferring can be found here. http://www.aroundandroid.com/tag/how-to-increase-android-phones-internal-memory-with-link2sd-app/