# Internal storage full but explorer shows less

Tags: internal-storage

My space in the internal storage is full and I can't install any more apps or even updates. But when I open the storage in Windows explorer I can't find the folder that cotains so much data. There are bunch that sum up to 50 MB only (the total size is 1,13 GB) and many folders show up as "0 bytes" in usage, which is strange.

DiskUsage app shows that "system data" takes 90% of the storage, but I can't figure out what to delete or uninstall to free some space. How or what can I delete to free up space (I believe that apps themselves can't take up this much storage, I don't have that many I think).

NOTE: I moved hopefully all the apps to the SD card before.

EDIT: Connecting my phone with USB to the computer and opening the device and the storage in Windows explorer.

Android version: 4.1.2

HTC Sense version: 5.0

Comment: Android version? How do you make your phone's storage show up in Explorer?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: As usual, I'd recommend to first take a look at the associated tag-wiki – here the one for [internal-storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/internal-storage/info) – and see if the first-aid there get's you started. Especially see: [Something is secretly eating up my tablet memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27127/16575) / [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575) / [My internal storage capacity is running low, what can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29416/16575) (linked from there)