# Why can't I move apps to the external memory on Huwait P8 lite 2017?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, huawei

I have a Huawei P8 Lite 2017 phone and it is slow as hell simply because the internal memory is almost full. I have a 64-G microSD card, but for some reason I can’t move any of my applications to that one. There are no ways to properly analyze and free space either.

In a nutshell the OS and the app date uses all my 16G internal memory.

It’s kind of annoying. Any suggestions what to do?

**UPDATE (15-Apr-2017): The main issue (as shown in the screenshot) is that some apps use a lot of internal memory and there is no way to move them to the SD card. Any ideas how to make that happen without rooting? It seems to be a common problem.
[image]**

Comment: What do you mean under *There are no ways to properly analyze and free space either*? What shows [storage menu applet](http://www.lawtechnologytoday.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/android-storage.png)?

Comment: @Suncatcher hi there. I have just updated the main post for more information. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/29419/94888).

Comment: No rooting needed, try this. Works for me. https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/auto-formatting-sdcard-to-internal-t3583875

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they have removed that option, I am using the same device and had previously using Marshmallow device. I do not have a storage issue though. This is the trick that worked for me, I changed the default storage to SD Card before I installed and updated apps. The app package is stored on internal memory but the data is on SD Card. However, my internal storage is always a minimum of 3GB and note that I have lot of apps, including games.

I guess if you change the storage type late, it doesn't move the data of apps to SD Card.

My advice is, backup your apps then reset your phone. Thereafter, initially  change the the default storage to SD Card then you can reinstall your apps.

Comment: That sounds good, but backups never work the way you want them. It's just too much hassle and something always goes wrong. Haha.