# Running TRIM from shell

Tags: adb, file-system, shell, system

Is it possible to run fstrim in stock android 4.3 from adb shell?

I understand it runs every 24 hours when the device is plugged in and idle but I would like to run on demand to test a few theories.

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: Any updates from your end? Don't forget to upvote and accept answer if it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**WARNING: I have not tested this procedure.**

You would need to have `fstrim` in `system/bin`. This [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=37244488&postcount=180) has a [DropBox download link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsjwnp9imhurb6s/fstrim).

start up `adb` and then switch users to root.

`$ adb shell` from your os terminal.

`$ su` to switch to the root user.

To copy fstrim to your `/system/bin` path you first need to mount the system path as Read/Write from adb or some other file manager

`# mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system` to mount /system as R/W

Then copy `fstrim` to the system path.

`# cp <pathtofstrim>/fstrim /system/bin`

Next you need to change permissions of fstrim to include execute.

`# chmod 766 /system/bin/fstrim` to make fstrim executable by root

After setting the correct permissions on `fstrim` you can run these commands from adb (as root):

`# fstrim -v /data`
`# fstrim -v /cache`
`# fstrim -v /system`

---

OR, you could go the **EASY WAY**. Install the [LagFix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grilledmonkey.lagfix) app, and trigger fstrim on demand, provided your device has fstrim support!

Comment: I'm running stock 4.3 and LagFix fails with permission error even though it has root. That looks promising but but I'm super hesitant given it has no comments. Not saying it's bad but I need to backup first. looking at it in a hex editor it has a number of good strings but since it's compiled who knows what it does :)

Comment: @hoss If you want to read more comments about LagFix, the developer has a thread for the app on XDA: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2104326 I say it's safe to use it. :)

Comment: Finally got LagFix working, I had to white list the app in su then clear the LagFix data then try again. Before I was getting a permission denied error even though it was white listed. I'll try this answer and see if it does as advertised.

Comment: I made some edits after doing some testing. The binary seems to be benign in that it doesn't seem to do anything malicious, and it seems to report that it did something but it's impossible to know if it did anything useful. I'll award this for the use of `LagFix` and if anyone can find an official fstrim bin that would complete the answer.

Comment: @hoss Did LagFix work? Did you download the fstrim on your phone, or did you download it on a Windows PC and copy it to your phone?

Comment: I did get LagFix working but I also tried the link you found and configured via adb.

Comment: Dropbox link is broken.

Comment: Do you mean permission=755 instead? Doesn't make sense to let non-root edit it.

Answer (score 2):

On newer versions, Android runs `fstrim` with a daily schedule, provided that the conditions meet. Or it should run on a reboot if not run for 3+ days. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213985/218526) for details.

However if you want to do `TRIM` manually, use Android's commandline tool **`sm fstrim`**. Previously this was `vdc fstrim dotrim` but added to Storage Manager in Oreo <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/31d0b7043d9077ad8a0ebfbd6ff2f98621e6f413%5E%21/#F0))</sup> and removed from `vold` in Pie <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/11c2d380a786d9e304416be98881b90b74ff666d))</sup>.

In order to send `FITRIM ioctl` to selected filesystem(s) only, use `fstrim` tool; a busybox applet.

Both commands require root, or `sm fstrim` can be executed from `adb shell`.

Answer (score 1):

vold, the (disk/eMMC) volume management daemon, has this built in.  Its shell client is called "vdc" (vold controller I guess, akin to rndc, remote name daemon controller for BIND).  The command and its relevant arguments, as the superuser, would be:

`vdc fstrim dotrim`

Note that at least on my tablet, 4.4.4, this will only trim `/cache` and `/data`, but this is mostly what I think you'd want.  You can see its progress with `logcat` (e.g., `logcat` from a shell on the device or `adb logcat` on a USB connected host).  Vold will output a message about each volume it trims and the fact that it's finished (in logcat).