# Nexus 7 2012 Lag: "mmcqd/0" process

Tags: nexus-7

I'm trying to fix lag on my 2012 N7 and recently formatted it's partitions to F2FS and tried two roms that are "All-F2FS", "SlimKat with All-F2FS support" and "BSZAospLP v1.5" but after I restore my apps with TB, which are around 100 apps, I get the lag and slowdown and the process causing it is "mmcqd/0".

Is there any way I can fix this and get rid of the lag?

I'm down to a point that don't care about customization and features of a Rom/Custom Rom, I just want a usable device.

Thanks.

Comment: try restoring a few apps at a time, one of them will be causing the lag
This question and answer may help: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35603/sluggish-performance-due-to-mmcqd-cpu-usage

Comment: Thanks, I uninstalled most of my apps, didn't help.